# how do I sync iBooks or move books between collections?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ipad, books

I have an Mac OSx 10.7.5 (doesn't come with iBooks) and iPad -- has iBooks in it.

I want to do a simple thing, create a new Collection, and move books from one collection to the other. I couldn't figure out how to do it on the iPad itself.

Well, I thought, I probably need to sync it to my Macbook, and do it there, nothing more than drag and drop.

But I can't find iBooks for my OSx (above) and iTunes doesn't sync that part of the iPad either.

What can I do to move some books from one collection to the other? Also, I want to copy quite a few PDFs to the iPad to iBook, is there a way to do it on the Macbook Pro with that version of OSx?

I got the latest version of iOS on the iPad.